# Typescript dynamic generic arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want a function that returns an object. The said function can also take n amount of functions as args, and use them to modify the object before returning it. My problem is that after doing the change I don't get the correct typescript type.

In this example I have the main function `getUser` and two modifier functions `modStatus`, `modAge`. When I call `getUser` with both modifiers I want to get `UserModStatus & UserModAge & User` as a return type

```
type User = {
  name: string;
};

type UserModAge = {
  age: number;
};

type UserModStatus = {
  status: "single" | "married";
};

type Mod<EXTRA> = <BASE>(user: BASE) => EXTRA & BASE;

const getUser = <T>(...mods: Mod<T>[]) => {
  const user: User = {
    name: "John",
  };

  return mods.reduce((acc, mod) => mod(acc), user);
};

const modAge: Mod<UserModAge> = (user) => {
  return { ...user, age: 21 };
};

const modStatus: Mod<UserModStatus> = (user) => {
  return { ...user, status: "married" };
};

const res = getUser(modStatus, modAge); // const res: User
```

However the return type is just the initial "User" type.

If I use static args it works fine

```
const getUser = <T, V>(mod1: Mod<T>, mod2: Mod<V>) => {
  const user: User = {
    name: "John",
  };

  return mod1(mod2(user));
};

const res = getUser(modStatus, modAge); // const res: UserModStatus & UserModAge & User
```

but I need them to be dynamic. Is there a way to achieve that?

The desired result is to get the correct type when applying different modifiers

```
const res = getUser();
// const res: User
```

```
const res = getUser(modAge);
// const res: UserModAge & User
```

```
const res = getUser(modStatus);
// const res: UserModStatus & User
```

```
const res = getUser(modStatus, modAge);
// const res: UserModStatus & UserModAge & User
```

Comment: please provide more examples of expected behavior. It is a bit unclear for me

Comment: Let me know if it helps https://catchts.com/chain-callbacks#short_way

Comment: This description isn't very clear. Please try to explain what you are attempting to do. For more information on how to write a good question please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that, but it needs some advanced types (or rather, I needed them). I will only show what I added, but the complete example can be inspected in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=51&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMBuTAX0c1ElgUQFkB7AEwCCtaGiw58IsrgCuhAEZJGLTG3DR4SPvwDKwfMBlxUGbOX2G4ZAERwatADYRrUAD5RrhfImoR%2015VZ2aG0AHgBRAA0AFQAlQQA%20E1CAIUEdcISACiMkMjSMgEpUJKi4wSgAMigC8NYAY15cCihCAWFSKDDNHnaRJLQcrmKUJPEoRAhDRFwMKAA6RdzEABooSU6AJgBGKBUVTEbm4FaBPQMjMm6ubXPLAaghpBGxs0np2fQFpa41igurB4vD4qH4XPtWAB6SFQAByEAA7lBgnBVNCoABhJoANyQwGMYXwuBACQA2gBdKA0YC8KBleK7dz0wSbNx0mLxADMi3mag4MFwVCaAHkAGaxKYyGbRdRwUIwKAQAAewAguH4BIEoSJJIpDwlHxlkHlpNkCiQ5ISaJhwAAFlRjA6oKLELxCFAAFb1fAOABeZFtwGAYCs0P%209QA1rxcYhRQ5eAj5o1CJCAI4yCAUIXNSEAVgADJyAOwAFgAnPmAByQyhEuCi3iIQgAWhkgqazeCnd4zepSAQ9WA2c76kw6IAClKwLwEFTZnancqiGAnGQsbgY-j2eVGdv4qymRzBJy5zS94JdtVmayr0fOXyNO3cNFeABJXCqxADodNeUPMxZAqyqquqxg6lAAD8jwRmQMCFKM2K8FQ-BQNIEAxsUwFqhqjxZDBc6ikgUCvvBCSIchxRQa%20qF4OhSDWlA0T2sY%20gRpm6w1Ok4SPD0c5QLwUpQN6CDFESKF9l%20ECDo6JwIlQdrnpe543ue3JjjCr4nD6cC0sm8g0OxdrQCisBPmKBpSs%20srrOqpnZi%2076ft%202YPl0AhUKKoL8BKcAyA4wCpFxazcMKAAiOiKiq2Gavw2rEmSlo4GgtRVHZTQOR%20-ZST%20uDymZ4qStKsqhCF4UJAkDRNC0IjALxaChNEkUgThhLxXqWQ8m0GpkNEhRXO5nl%20D5fkBT0azRAMrw4EcLTLLBXAmOMOAEMQNgAFK8LauDWCsZgHDg7yWacGrzJM-AyPUEBZFk%20D1PUaxdS8x03XdhRrMsolgcSgSqIcVUnJMxhoDVPRZF1dxGA9fQQIU9BQOiM0A5m830eisK6W6YBUE4yBIK6X42eJmUOA4DpqggmCA-MGxw5TmbzCtECMFT-yWIwQA):

```js
// nothing new added to the next line, but im referring often to Mod and the EXTRA generic.
type Mod<EXTRA> = <BASE>(user: BASE) => EXTRA & BASE;
// Converts Mod<any>[] into EXTRA1 | EXTRA2 | EXTRA3...
type UnionOfReturnTypes<U extends Mod<any>[]> = ReturnType<U[number]>

// Converts EXTRA1 | EXTRA2 | EXTRA3 into EXTRA1 & EXTRA2 & EXTRA3
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

// This takes a BASE (User in our case) and intersects it with EXTRA1 & EXTRA2 & EXTRA3.
// It also combines the types UnionOfReturnTypes and UnionToIntersection
type ModifiedResult<BASE, MODS extends Mod<any>[]>  = BASE & UnionToIntersection<UnionOfReturnTypes<MODS>>;

const getUser = <T extends Mod<any>[]>(...mods: T) => {
  const user: User = {
    name: "John",
  };

  return mods.reduce((acc, mod) => mod(acc), user) as ModifiedResult<User, T>;
};


const res = getUser(modStatus, modAge); // const res: User
// No compiler errors and intellisense
res.age; 
res.name;
res.status;
```

**Explanation:**

`UnionOfReturnTypes`: This type is using [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) and [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to combine all return types from the `Mod` functions. But it can only extract the `EXTRA` types, since the `BASE` information is only available when an argument is actually passed, which can't happen in a type. Thus the result is `EXTRA1 | EXTRA2 | EXTRA3` and so on for every `Mod` that was used.

`UnionToIntersection` this code is from an [answer of jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type), and we need this to transform our union into an intersection. The union that `UnionOfReturnTypes` returns won't help us much since our wanted result of `user` is not:

```
type finalUser = {name: string} | {age: number} | {status: "married" | "single"}
```

but the following result:

```
type finalUser = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  status: "married" | "single"
};
```

And exactly this does `UnionToIntersection` for us, it converts `EXTRA1 | EXTRA2` -> `EXTRA1 & EXTRA2`

`ModifiedResult` this is the type that combines `UnionToIntersection` and `UnionOfReturnTypes` and also adds the base we couldn't extract from `UnionOfReturnTypes`. This finalizes the solution and now lets us dynamically add mods to `getUser()` and get the full type returned.

Comment: If interested, I can also try to explain in simple words how UnionToIntersection actually works. It might be a challenge, though =)